# How does the fundamental theorem of calculus work for 2 variables?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The fundamental theorem of calculus for a single variables states the following:
Let:
$$U(x)=\int{f(x)}dx$$
Then:
$$\frac{d}{dx}U(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int{f(x)}dx=f(x)$$

Now let $U$ be a function of 2 variables such that:
$$U(x,t)=\int{f(x,t)} dx$$
In this case, how would we find $U_x$ and $U_t$? Is the following correct?
$$U_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}U(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\int{f(x,t)}dx=f(x)$$
$$U_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}U(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\int{f(x,t)}dx=f(t)$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ill-posed, perhaps you want to ask if $U(x,t)=\displaystyle\int f(x,t,s)ds$, what will happen to $U_{x}$ and $U_{t}$. If the partial derivatives $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ exist, continuous, and integrable, then Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem implies that $U_{x}=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t,s)ds$ and $U_{t}=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t,s)ds$.